# C# Collection<T>.Remove(T item) not working though object data is equal

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections

I got two collections, where one is for the Book objects and one for the BookViewModel objects.
When I remove a Book object from the BookCollection an CollectionChanged Event is triggered so that the BookViewModelCollection can delete it's BookViewModel version of the book. So heres the delegate function which is bound to the event.

> BookViewModelCollection.cs

```
private void ModelCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (syncDisabled == false)
    {
        syncDisabled = true;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var book in e.NewItems.OfType<Book>().Select(v => new BookViewModel(v)))
                {
                    this.Add(book);
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var book in e.OldItems.OfType<Book>().Select(v => new BookViewModel(v)))
                {
                    this.Remove(book);
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                this.Clear();
                break;
        }
        syncDisabled = false;
    }
}
```

Maybe there's an error converting from Book to BookViewModel? The code is being executed but the Remove method returns false and the object is still in the collection although the data is the same on both objects. The BookViewModel holds an object of type Book and the constructor simply does the following:

> BookViewModel.cs

```
public BookViewModel(Book b)
{
     this.Book = b;
}
```

Book is a property which sets the local variable of Book.

NOTE: On the other way, updating the BookCollection when the BookCollectionViewModel has changed works perfectly fine with the same technique.

I hope anyone can help me. If you need more/other information just tell me. I could also upload the files on Github.

Best regards

Comment: Reference this with a value(same as the book you removed) and use it in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remove method has this documentation on MSDN:

> If type T implements the IEquatable generic interface, the equality
>   comparer is the Equals method of that interface; otherwise, the
>   default equality comparer is Object.Equals.

Since you have not implemented `IEquatable<T>`, the default equality comparer will be used. What this means is that the `Remove` method will check if the item you want to remove has the same reference as one of the objects in the collection. This is clearly not the case because one items is one object while the other is a different object: 2 different references.

```
foreach( var book in e.OldItems.OfType<Book>().Select( v => new BookViewModel( v ) ) ) {
   this.Remove( book );
}
```

What you are doing in the above is creating a bunch of `BookViewModel` (s) and then trying to remove them from your collection. But you just created that `book` so it never existed in your collection before.

If you want to be able to do that, then at the very least you should implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface on your types so the `Remove` method can use that to figure out if the item you want to remove is in the collection but not only using a reference equality but some other equality.

Here is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) (and I copied the code below) which does equality checking by checking if 2 parts have the same PartId. Even if the objects are different objects (references).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// Simple business object. A PartId is used to identify the type of part 
// but the part name can change. 
public class Part : IEquatable<Part> {
   public string PartName { get; set; }

   public int PartId { get; set; }

   public override string ToString() {
      return "ID: " + PartId + "   Name: " + PartName;
   }
   public override bool Equals(object obj) {
      if( obj == null )
         return false;
      Part objAsPart = obj as Part;
      if( objAsPart == null )
         return false;
      else
         return Equals( objAsPart );
   }
   public override int GetHashCode() {
      return PartId;
   }
   public bool Equals(Part other) {
      if( other == null )
         return false;
      return ( this.PartId.Equals( other.PartId ) );
   }
   // Should also override == and != operators.

}
```

And as a final note you may come across `IComparable<T>` also so here is the difference:

`IEquatable<T>` tests whether two objects are equal. This is what you need.

`IComparable<T>` is used for ordering to indicate which object comes before another object during sorting. For example, to sort the numbers 5, 1 it will tell you 1 comes before 5 for doing an ascending ordering. IEquatable will tell you that 1 does not equal 5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. So do I have to implement the comparing Equals() method logic by myself?

Comment: At the very least, you should do that.

Comment: Yeah ofc. So thanks that solved my problem. Works like a charm. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The code is being executed but the Remove method returns false and the
>   object is still in the collection although the data is the same on
>   both objects.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx) `Remove()` method use default equality comparer. By default, objects are not same if they have same value properties. Two objects are same if they have same reference.

I think you struggling with this. You have object with same properties but not same references.

To fix this you can do example two things: implement your comparer or manually remove element which satisfy condition.

If you decide to implement your comparer you can follow this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) article. Basically you will need to implement `IComparer<T>`.

In case that you using `List<Book>` you can follow MSDN and implement `IEquatable<Book>` on your `Book`.

```
public class Book: IEquatable<Book>
{        
    // TODO: Implement your logic.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline with what has already been said.  You could just find the reference in `this` with the same book values:

```
foreach (var book in e.OldItems.OfType<Book>())
{
    BookViewModel tempBVM = this.Where(x => x.Book.name == book.name &&
       c.Book.author == book.author).FirstOrDefault();
    if(tempBVM != null)
    {
        this.Remove(tempBVM);
    }
}
```

I just took a guess at what properties you might have in the Book class and what you might need for comparison.